# MapReduce wordcount get unique key

Tags: mapreduce

I try to understand how MapReduce is working on the simplest example possible : a wordcount.

Take the sentence "I am a newbie and I eat a potato".

I split it in two parts, "I am a newbie " and "and I eat a potato", that I send to two mappers. These mappers answer me :

```
I --> 1
am --> 1
a --> 1
newbie --> 1
```

for the first one and

```
and --> 1
I --> 1
eat --> 1
a --> 1
potato --> 1
```

for the second one.

So now, on the master i have this data :

```
I --> 1
am --> 1
a --> 1
newbie --> 1
and --> 1
I --> 1
eat --> 1
a --> 1
potato --> 1
```

But my reducers take a Map in entry that is to say the key is unique. So i have to convert the data I have to this :

```
I --> 1, 1
am --> 1
a --> 1, 1
newbie --> 1
and --> 1
eat --> 1
potato --> 1
```

and then my reducers just sum the numbers.

It seems that this is the most important part of the algorithm because it's here that all the job is done. And very surprisingly i can't find anything about this on the internet. They all provide graphs and diagrams with the phase "Sorting and shuffling" (where shuffling is just sending data to the right reducer and sorting is sorting the keys ?) but nothing more.

How is this phase working ? Who is taking care of that ? Is it another phase of mapping, or does the master do the job itself ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add up the numbers of each of the keys?

You currently have an array of word:arrayOfNumbers pairs that you want to **map** to an array of word:totalOccurrances pairs.

You will have to **reduce** each arrayOfNumbers to totalOccurrances.

so something like

```
keyArrayPairs.map(array => array.reduce((result, value) => result + value, 0))
```

EDIT

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
When you reduce an object, one of the arguments to resolve function is the key. You could do something like

```
array.reduce((result, value, word) => {
  if(result[word]){
    result.push(value[0]) 
  }else{
    result[word]=value
  }
  return result
},{}) // Empty object
```

Comment: I have an array of word:arrayOfNumbers, where all arrayOfNumbers is [1] so summing it to have totalOccurances would not do anything.

Comment: (I don't want to sum it, i want to gather it by key, that's slightly different.)

Comment: Your Edit --> That means that i can't split it in two different reducers, i have to reduce all the data at once (imagine a text rather than this short sentence, it would be very long).

Comment: I assumed your ' on the master ' data for this reducer. What do you you mean with splitting it?

Comment: Different mappers --> Data with not unique key --> Data with unique key --> Different reducers. That's what i want (and how Hadoop works btw, using sorting (TeraSort), but i don't really understand how it's working)

Comment: Ok, so the reducer in the edit takes care of the 3rd step, which step are you struggling with?

Comment: Yes. But imagine a 1million line data, this method is not affordable.

Comment: So don't feed it all the data, and then call reducers on the result of each of the reducers

Answer (score 0):

> So i have to convert the data I have to this :

No, you don't! MapReduce does this for you. All you have to do is provide a map and a reduce function, so that you create the proper keys and values for each phase. The output keys that you will create in the map function (key=word, value=1) is all you have to do. Then, MapReduce (not you) will group those key-value pairs by key, and in the reduce function you just define what you want to do with each group of key-value pairs that have the same key (i.e., with all the 1's that have been grouped for the same word). The answer is that you want to sum them, so that you get the final frequency of each word.

Also, the statement:

> So now, on the master i have this data :

is wrong. The master does not know anything about the key-value pairs. If you are not working on a cluster, imagine that each computer in a cluster knows only what the same node has processed and nothing more. Read a little bit more about how MapReduce works and don't worry if you don't get it the first time. It takes a while to get used to this logic. You should always try to think of you program as a distributed program running on a cluster and not on a single computer.

Comment: Who is "MapReduce" ? MapReduce is an algorithm, not a person or a software ! I'm not using any framework. If your answer is "use Hadoop, the sort phase will be done for you" then it's not what I want, definitely. The second part is non sense for the same reason : the master is my server so i'm pretty sure I get this data on it (it's just a NodeJs server)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know what MapReduce is. I really thought it was a person. You seem to have found the answer already. Good luck and apologies for my nonsense!

Comment: No haven't found the answer yet :( i'm pretty sure you understood my point,  "Then, MapReduce (not you) will group those key-value pairs by key" does not mean anything, who is the "MapReduce" you're talking about ? I only have a js file with a function map and a function reduce, nothing more. This job has to be done somewhere (grouping the key-value pairs).